# Prevent PHP, PDO, and MySQL/MariaDB from returning integers as strings without disabling ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following schema:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| someInt | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I run the following script, the integers are returned as strings.

```
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host={$db['host']};dbname={$db['dbname']};charset={$db['charset']}",$db['username'],$db['password'],array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>true,\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
var_dump($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM integerTesting')->fetchAll());

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 1"
    ["someInt"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 2"
    ["someInt"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 3"
    ["someInt"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

So, I change `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `FALSE`, and get the results I am looking for:

```
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host={$db['host']};dbname={$db['dbname']};charset={$db['charset']}",$db['username'],$db['password'],array(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>true,\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
var_dump($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM integerTesting')->fetchAll());

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 1"
    ["someInt"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 2"
    ["someInt"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 3"
    ["someInt"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Did I answer my own question?  No as my questions specifically states without disabling `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`.  Why does this matter?  Because doing so apparently breaks.  My original question is below, but I know realize this is not really a Doctrine question but a PDO/MySQL question.

I have the following Doctrine entity:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="integerTesting")
 **/
class IntegerTesting
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Column( type="integer")
     */
    protected $someInt;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSomeInt()
    {
        return $this->someInt;
    }
    public function setSomeInt($someInt)
    {
        $this->someInt = $someInt;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I add a couple or records and then read some records both Doctrine's findAll() method as well as a direct PDO query:

```
<?php
require_once "bootstrap.php";

function addRow(int $i, $entityManager):void {
    $e = new IntegerTesting();
    $e->setName("Name $i");
    $e->setSomeInt($i);
    $entityManager->persist($e);
    $entityManager->flush();
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    addRow($i, $entityManager);
}

//Using Doctrine's findAll() method
var_dump($entityManager->getRepository('IntegerTesting')->findAll());

//Using direct PDO query
var_dump($entityManager->getConnection()->query('SELECT * FROM integerTesting')->fetchAll());
```

The output using Doctrine's findAll() method returns the integer columns as the desired integer type.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(IntegerTesting)#61 (3) {
    ["id":protected]=>
    int(4)
    ["name":protected]=>
    string(6) "Name 1"
    ["someInt":protected]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(IntegerTesting)#63 (3) {
    ["id":protected]=>
    int(5)
    ["name":protected]=>
    string(6) "Name 2"
    ["someInt":protected]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(IntegerTesting)#64 (3) {
    ["id":protected]=>
    int(6)
    ["name":protected]=>
    string(6) "Name 3"
    ["someInt":protected]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

The direct query, however, returns them as strings which is not desired:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 1"
    ["someInt"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 2"
    ["someInt"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Name 3"
    ["someInt"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

I found a solution by setting `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `FALSE`, however, after painstaking troubleshooting, found that it breaks some other aspects of Doctrine (class type inheritance, and maybe other functionality).

How should one prevent Doctrine from returning integers as strings?

Comment: In the Symfony example, the object gets hydrated with the data and that's why it has the correct data types. In the second example you are using PDO with MySQL. By default it will return either strings or null. You either change the MySQL driver to mysqlnd, use symfony's built in methods, or cast the results from the PDO query.

Answer (score 1):

In php-8.1.0RC1/ are native types even for EMULATE_PREPARES,
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.1.0RC1/UPGRADING#L130
So in future it should be possible to fix this by upgrading PHP to 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Well, guess it doesn't technically answer the question as I am disabling `\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`.  It works for me, however, since I can do so on a per query basis and therefore do not upset Doctrine.

```
    $pdo = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection();
    $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
```